# writing program, where the computer guesses a number that user chooses -PHP

Tags: php, hiddenfield

user doesn't need to submit a number etc. Just think one in their mind.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="EN" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>guess_game</title>
</head>

<body>

>if guess is too low, user presses 'low button' (same with high button)

<p>think of a number, 1-100.</p>
<form method="post">
<button type="submit" name="low">too low</button>
<button type="submit" name="high">too high</button>
<button type="submit" name="match">it's a match</button>
</form> 

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['low'])) 
{
>store $guess to be lowest number range of guess
 $low = $guess; 
}
else{$low=1;}

if (isset($_POST['high'])) 
{
$high = $guess; 
}
else{$high=100;}

if (isset($_POST['match'])) 
{
print "thank you for playing";
}
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="hLow" id="hLow" value="<?php $low ?>">

>store $low,High vars to hidden field

<input type="hidden" name="hHigh" id="hHigh" value="<?php $high ?>">
</form>

<?php

>place values stored in hidden back to php var.

$hlow=$_POST['hLow'];   
$hhigh=$_POST['hHigh'];

$guess=rand($hlow,$hhigh);
print "is the number $guess"; 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

so far this code won't pass any value to hidden field.($guess is always 0)
  I want $guess to be random numbers between $low and $high(that are stored in hidden)

Comment: You need to put the hidden fields in the _same_ form as the submit buttons. Also, you don't want to reset `$low` to 1 if the uses says your current guess is to high.

Comment: You shouldn't have an apostrophe in XHTML, as in `it's`.

Comment: @PHPglue: that's nonsense. Utter nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't putting `$guess` into the form. Put this in after you have calculated `$guess`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="hGuess" id="hGuess" value="<?php $guess ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php
$guess = 'Think of a number between 1 and 100.';
if(isset($_POST['low']) || isset($_POST['high'])){
  $guess = 'The Computer will have to guess again.'
}
elseif(isset($_POST['match'])){
  $guess = 'The Computer just read your mind....Not.';
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <title>GUESSING GAME</title>
    <style type='text/css'>
      @import 'common.css'; @import 'game.css';
    </style>
  </head>
<body class='njs'>
  <p><?php echo $guess;?></p>
  <form method='post' action='<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>'>
    <input type='submit' name='low' value='too low' />
    <input type='submit' name='high' value='too high' />
    <input type='submit' name='match' value='it&#039;s a match' />
  </form>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='common.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```